# Do a couple need to purify themselves after copulation?

Tags: marriage, sex

In Islam and Christianity, it is obligatory for a couple to take a shower to purify themselves. I have never heard of such a thing from any of my Hindu friends.

Are there any teachings related to this? I have been reading other teachings about purification, like the menstrual question on this site, which says that a woman needs to be clean.

Is there any teaching which tells a couple to get clean after copulation?

Comment: at least the most probable place for such things to exist, The Manusmriti doesn't mention any such cleaning ritual after sex.

Comment: most Hindu students do not know anything about scriptures because the education system is supposed to be 'secular'

Comment: Hi Afzaal, "Tat Tvam Asi"'s answer is more correct than mine. Please choose that as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. According to [Apastamba Dharma Sutra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/apastamba-dharma-sutra/d/doc116265.html), couples need to purify themselves after copulation. From Praśna II, Paṭala 1, Khaṇḍa 1,

> 18. Let him have connubial intercourse in the interval also, if his wife (desires it, observing the restrictions imposed by the law).
> 19. (The duty of) connubial intercourse (follows from) the passage of a Brāhmaṇa, ('Let us dwell together until a son be born.')
> 20. But during intercourse he shall be dressed in a particular dress kept for this purpose.
> 21. And during intercourse only they shall lie together,
> 22. **Afterwards separate.**
> 23. **Then they both shall bathe**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80389/discussion-on-answer-by-narayana-sharma-do-a-couple-need-to-purify-themselves-af).

Answer (score 1):

Hinduism & Indian culture before western influence did not view sexual activity as a taboo or unclean act.

In many parts of India, there are photos from older eras that show women being topless and temple sculptures etc. The fact that these are on temples would indicate advanced civilisation and architecture.

Sources (mouseover to view hidden images)

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

There are also ancient manuscripts such as Kama Sutra ("Manuscript of Love") that go into detail regarding love and sexual relations.

As such, before the Portuguese (Catholic), Muslims & British (Protestant) introduced their puritan and prudish views, India was quite liberated, and did not view sex as a vile act needing "cleansing".

This does not mean Indians were unhygienic or not clean. To the contrary, travelers to India, such as Marco Polo, have observed and recorded that Indians bathed multiple times a day and were quite fastidious about being clean.

> The people here go into battle with lance and shield and they go stark naked.[...]
>   Another one of their customs is that all of them, male and female, wash their whole body in cold water twice a day - this is, morning and evening. One who did not wash twice a day would be thought an ascetic, as we think of the Patarins.

*[The Travels, Marco Polo, c. 1300 AD](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=HLxwRuyH_P0C&lpg=PT322&dq=marco%20polo%20indians%20washing%20twice%20daily&pg=PT322#v=onepage&q&f=false)*

So I'd presume that once business is done, couple would proceed to wash all that sweat off ;)

Comment: Currently, this seems more as opinion based answer. please provide source.

Comment: Updated with sources as per your request, @Mr_Green

Comment: "Is there any teaching which tells a couple to get clean after copulation?" Looks like OP needs answer from Authoritative scriptures.

Comment: @a20 The Kama Sutra is not a part of Hinduism. Just FYI.

Comment: @AravindSuresh you're commenting on a 5 year old post bro, FYI.